# Hide or Disable Related Posts on Product Description when there aren't any?

Tags: magento2, product-page, related-products, product-description

Can anyone help with this please? Please see the image attached. So assuming this is a template fix.
Currently shows when there are related posts.

But most products dont have it. How can you hide when not added to the page?

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: do you have access to template file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have template file access so please set if conditions on it.

**For Ex:** Check the value is empty or not? If the value is not empty then set your content.